# Change tracking is not supported on queries with QUALIFY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, change-tracking

I am trying to create a Stream on top of a VIEW. The VIEW joins to other multiple VIEWs that use QUALIFY to get the latest record for each PK from base tables.

Snowflake gives me the following error when I try to create this Stream:

```
Change tracking is not supported on queries with QUALIFY.
```

What are my options? Thanks.

Note:

```
Change tracking is not supported on queries with window functions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Streams on views with the following operations are not yet supported:

```
- GROUP BY clauses
- QUALIFY clauses
- Subqueries not in the FROM clause
- Correlated subqueries
- LIMIT clauses
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro.html#streams-on-views).